(Permission) Issue running electrum server as a service in Raspberry Pi 5
Disclaimer: Having some linux permissions issues, but it is related to setting up a Bitcoin Node, and an Electrum Server; if there's a better place to post this, please lmk!.
I've been following the RaspiBolt guide in order to setup a Bitcoin Node, an Electrum Server (electrs). I'm doing this in Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS.
In the guide, the OS is booted from an external hard drive; I'm booting from the Pi 5's micro SSD card; I have the entire Bitcoin blockchain AND the electrs indexes stored in a mounted SSD
In the Bitcoin client section, the guide has you create a user and gives it access to run the bitcoin daemon. Later, it has you setup a service so that the bitcoin daemon automatically starts when the machine starts. By adding an entry in /etc/fstab, I've managed to get the external drive to be mounted when the machine starts, and I'm mounting it with the bitcoin user both as user and group owner; the service works just as expected.
However, I'm not having the same luck with the electr service the guide also has you setup. When I try starting electrs as the electrs user, the server crashes because it doesn't have read/write permissions to the folder in the external drive where the electrs db is stored.
What might be a good solution for this? Is there a way to mount the drive with access to multiple users? The electrs user IS in the bitcoin group, so I thought that should have sufficed to access the mounted drive?

does every folder in the path to data (including parent folders all the way up to the root folder) have both read and execute (traverse folder) permissions for either Bitcoin group or world?

I think they may not have? I had added an entry to /etc/fstab automatically mount my external drive at boot time. I was searching around and added umask=002 as part of the entry's options, and after that it worked. What exactly does 002 mean?
